# Converting string to NSData and NSData back to string

Tags: typescript, nativescript-plugin

I have the following code:

```
const content: NSString = NSString.stringWithString(data);
console.log("content#1: " + content);
const nsData: NSData = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
console.log("nsData#1: " + nsData);
console.log("nsData#2: " + nsData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(null));
NSString.new().initWithDataEncoding(nsData, NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

1. "data" is a Typescript string containing "DetErHemmeligt"
2. Line 2 prints out "DetErHemmeligt"
3. Line 4 always prints out "<44657445 7248656d 6d656c69 6774>"
4. Line 5 works as well
5. Line 6 crashes with no error logging, and I have tried many things here like "initWithBytesLengthEncoding", but it just keeps crashing for me and I can not figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey there! What is the "import" on a TS to have to recognize Obj-c headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are writing objective-c code through NativeScript here which would translate to:

```
[[NSString new] initWithData:nsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem with this is that your object has already been initialized. The `new` call in objective-c is actually shorthand for `alloc` followed by `init`.

```
[[[NSString alloc] init] initWithData:nsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Since you can't `init` an object twice, your app crashes. Instead, try using `alloc`.

```
NSString.alloc().initWithDataEncoding(nsData, NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

Comment: Oh my... its been years since I did any ObjC coding, thank you very much :)